# WP_query problem -spurious results

Tags: wp-query

What am I missing?

```
<?  
//Specialities Query 
$args = array( 
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post__in' => array(24, 26, 28),
 ) ;

$specialities_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop   
while ( $specialities_query->have_posts() ) :
 $specialities_query->the_post(); ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Read more on %s', 'karenmann' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="show"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<? endwhile;
/* Restore original Post Data */ 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

returns 5 pages, id 7, 11 and then the three above 24,26,28.
This query is in a sidebar and I normally manage these quite well
I was originally using post_parent but also getting spurious results though slightly different to this and, at the end, including these three posts.

Site: development.karenmann.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids 7 & 11 are probably `sticky posts`.

Try this:

```
$args = array( 
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post__in' => array(24, 26, 28),
 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
```

Comment: Well done! And the reason they are sticky posts.... because I've been trying the WP front end editor and it seems to make pages sticky for some reason.